# Query pasword on Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

It is possible to achieve the following?

```
    if fieldDeleteAccountPassword.text == PFUser.currentUser()?.password! {

        println("PASSWORD MATCH")
        PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackground()

    }
    else
    {
        println("PASSWORD NOT MATCH")
    }
```

At the moment all I got with `PFUser.currentUser()?.password!` is a nil. I imagine that should be possible otherwise why adding a .password to the PFUser if it is not accessible?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot read a users password. You can only write to it.

If you want to check if a string is the same as a user's password, try logging them in, you will get an error if it's wrong